# Track progress for method iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, progress-bar, observer-pattern

Generally speaking, is there a way to track the progress of completion of a method? With some sort of observer or something of the like.

I have been looking but there are only references about how to implement it with internet requests. I know how to do that, but I want to track progress of a specific method. Is it possible?

In this case the method that I want to track is UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum. I know not if it is possible. I am specially interested if it is possible generally.

Thanks a lot for the suggestions!!

Comment: Are you interested in just completion or the amount completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common coding patterns for progress updates for functions/methods that operate asynchronously:

1. The asynchronous function/method could take a [selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) as a parameter and that method can be called as documented. This is useful when simply reporting the completion of some asynchronous event, such as in `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.
2. There are [protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocProtocols.html) (in which your background process will have some `delegate` property that defines which object will conform to the protocol and thereby be notified of key events or progress).
3. There are [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) in which the background process notifies via [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and for which objects will invoke `addObserver` in order to receive the notifications.

If you're writing your own background process, you can use any of these techniques (I generally use delegates), but if you're using some existing framework or third party library, you're reliant upon whatever notification/delegate interfaces they may have provided. And if the framework/library does not provide any such interface, you're largely out of luck.

In the case of [`UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW41) you only have the `completionTarget` and `completionSelector` to asynchronously notify you of the completion of the process (e.g. so you could have some [`UIActivityIndicatorView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) spinner showing that the save is in progress and then stopping the activity indicator in your `completionSelector`), but I don't think there is any interim progress interface for this function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer. Indeed it was what I thought, i had hope just maybe I could make a proper progress indicator. But I guess it depends if the method really allows it.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of progress indicators seen in software are in fact faked, or at best indicating portions of an operation complete rather than time (not always the same).   This is clearly going to be the case where there isn't something tangible to measure, or in cases where there is, a means measure it.

In the case of `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` there appears to be no way of getting notification of partial completion - only full completion.

It is quite noticeable in modern UI design practice that progress indicators are now often not showing the proportion of an operation complete.   There is a school of thought that showing an indicator which doesn't show proportion completed is better than one showing the wrong proportion.

If you wanted to go down the route of faking a progress indicator,  your best bet is to measure the time taken for the operation during development and animate your progress indicator on this basis.   After a few operation you'll be able to refine the estimate.    Clearly, users are unlikely to complain about an operation taking less time than the progress indicator shows, but they'll notice when it takes significantly more.   You might choose to exceed expectations and lengthen your initial estimate.

Apple used to use precisely this trick on the UI shown on boot on older versions of MacOSX.  They refined their estimate on each successive boot.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marko, it is indeed a good idea to fake it. Although I am reluctant to do it, due to best practices brain wash.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general solution. It depends whether the author of the method in question has provided a way to request callbacks or interrogate for progress.

It seems from the documentation that `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` only provides a completion callback, so there's no way to get regular updates.